# gitlab-runner locally - No such command sh

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have gitlab-runner installed locally.

```
km@Karls-MBP ~ $ gitlab-runner --version
Version:      10.4.0
Git revision: 857480b6
Git branch:   10-4-stable
GO version:   go1.8.5
Built:        Mon, 22 Jan 2018 09:47:12 +0000
OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
```

Docker:

```
km@Karls-MBP ~ $ docker --version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker/compose:1.19.0

before_script:
  - echo wtf

test:
  script:
    - echo test
```

Results:

```
km@Karls-MBP ~ $ sudo gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-privileged test
WARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of upcoming releases 
WARNING: You most probably have uncommitted changes. 
WARNING: These changes will not be tested.         
Running with gitlab-runner 10.4.0 (857480b6)
  on  ()
Using Docker executor with image docker/compose:1.19.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:be4b46f2adbc8534c7f6738279ebedd6106969695f5e596079e89e815d375d9c for predefined container...
Pulling docker image docker/compose:1.19.0 ...
Using docker image docker/compose:1.19.0 ID=sha256:e06b58ce9de2ea3f11634e022ec814984601ea3a5180440c2c28d9217b713b30 for build container...
Running on runner--project-0-concurrent-0 via x.x.x...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/project-0'...
done.
Checking out b5a262c9 as km/ref...
Skipping Git submodules setup
No such command: sh

Commands:
  build              Build or rebuild services
  bundle             Generate a Docker bundle from the Compose file
  config             Validate and view the Compose file
  create             Create services
  down               Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes
  events             Receive real time events from containers
  exec               Execute a command in a running container
  help               Get help on a command
  images             List images
  kill               Kill containers
  logs               View output from containers
  pause              Pause services
  port               Print the public port for a port binding
  ps                 List containers
  pull               Pull service images
  push               Push service images
  restart            Restart services
  rm                 Remove stopped containers
  run                Run a one-off command
  scale              Set number of containers for a service
  start              Start services
  stop               Stop services
  top                Display the running processes
  unpause            Unpause services
  up                 Create and start containers
  version            Show the Docker-Compose version information
```

Don't really know what the issue is.

Comment: **No such command: sh** ! In which step you use this command ?

Comment: @LyesCHIOUKH That's what I'm thinking! I have no idea, everything I posted in the question is what I know :/ I have no idea! The help menu that is displayed under is from the "docker-compose". I'm guessing the image I'm using has an Entrypoint that is incorrect?

Answer (score 15):

It seems that the `docker/compose` image is configured with `docker-compose` as an entrypoint.

You can [override the default entrypoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#overriding-the-entrypoint-of-an-image) of the docker/compose image in your **.gitlab-ci.yml** file :

```
image: 
  name: docker/compose:1.19.0
  entrypoint: [""]

before_script:
  - echo wtf

test:
  script:
    - echo test
```

Answer (score 3):

The [docker/compose](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose) image has the command `docker-compose` as its entrypoint (until version 1.24.x), which enables a usage similar to this (assuming a compatible volume mount):

```
docker run --rm -t docker/compose -f some-dir/compose-file.yml up
```

Unfortunately that same feature makes it incompatible with usage within GitLab CI’s Docker Runner. Theoretically you could have a construct like this:

```
job-name:
    image: docker/compose:1.24.1
    script:
        - up
        - --build
        - --force-recreate
```

But the GitLab Docker Runner assumes the entrypoint is `/bin/bash` - or at least functions likewise (many Docker images thoughtfully use a shell script with `"$@"` as its final line for the entrypoint) - and from the array elements that you specify for the script, it creates its own temporary shell script on the fly. It starts with statements like `set -e` and `set -o pipeline` and will be used in a statement like `sh temporary-script.sh` as the container command. That’s what causes the unexpected error message you got.

This behaviour was recently [documented more clearly](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-entrypoint):

> The Docker executor doesn’t overwrite the ENTRYPOINT of a Docker image.
>
> That means that if your image defines the ENTRYPOINT and doesn’t allow to run scripts with CMD, the image will not work with the Docker executor.

Overriding the entrypoint with `[""]` will allow usage of `docker/docker-compose` (before version 1.25.x) with the Docker Runner, but the script that GitLab will create on the fly is not going to run as process 1 and because of that the container will not stop at the end of the script. Example:

```
job-name:
    image:
        name: docker/docker-compose
        entrypoint: [""]
    script:
        - docker-compose
        - up
        - --build
        - --force-recreate
```

At the time I write this the latest version of `docker/docker-compose` is 1.25.0-rc2. Your mileage may vary, but it suffices for my purposes and entirely resolves both problems.